# Web locked CSV to dataframe in r

Tags: r, csv, rstudio-server

I have a file on a private web server I am trying to access.  I must first go to a site and login with my credentials and then I can type a URL (there is no link) to access the file, which immediately downloads a csv file to the computer.  I am trying to get that csv file to automatically load into R either direct from online or have it automatically download and uploaded from my hard drive

I am going to be refreshing this data 10-15 times a day which is why I need it automatic rather than manually downloading it every time.

I have tried a with several packages and have been impressed with Hadley's package rvest which has shown much easier than some things I have used in the past.  I am succeeding in downloading the data:

```
library(rvest)
fs <- html_session("somewebsite.org")
fs.login <- fs %>% follow_link("Sign In")
login.form <- html_form(fs.login)[[1]]
login.form <-set_values(login.form, userName = "myusername", password =      "mypassword")
active.session <- submit_form(fs.login, login.form)
my.data <- jump_to(active.session, "somewebsite.org/report/groups")
```

I have ran it with a timer several times and it takes an average of 27 seconds which indicates it is downloading the file (roughly the same amount that it takes Google Chrome). The result is a variable class session with 7 elements 43.7 Mb

```
my.data
```

> somewebsite/report/groups
>
> Status: 200
>
> Type:   text/csv
>
> Size:   45856046

My question is how can I access the actual csv file or data in r?

```
str(my.data)

List of 7  
 $ handle  :List of 2  
  ..$ handle:Class 'curl_handle' <externalptr>   
  ..$ url   : chr "somewebsite.org"  
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "handle"  
 $ config  :List of 7  
  ..$ method    : NULL  
  ..$ url       : NULL  
  ..$ headers   : NULL  
  ..$ fields    : NULL  
  ..$ options   :List of 1  
  .. ..$ autoreferer: int 1  
  ..$ auth_token: NULL  
  ..$ output    : NULL  
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "request"  
 $ url     : chr "https://somewebsite.org/report/groups"  
 $ back    : chr "https://somewebsite.org/report/groups"  
 $ forward : chr(0)   
 $ response:List of 10  
  ..$ url        : chr "https://somewebsite.org/report/groups"  
  ..$ status_code: int 200  
  ..$ headers    :List of 6  
  .. ..$ content-disposition: chr "attachment; filename=\"groups-2016-0318-063749.csv\""  
  .. ..$ content-type       : chr "text/csv"  
  .. ..$ date               : chr "Fri, 18 Mar 2016 18:37:49 GMT"  
  .. ..$ server             : chr "Apache-Coyote/1.1"  
  .. ..$ transfer-encoding  : chr "chunked"  
  .. ..$ connection         : chr "Close"  
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"  
  ..$ all_headers:List of 1  
  .. ..$ :List of 3  
  .. .. ..$ status : int 200  
  .. .. ..$ version: chr "HTTP/1.1"  
  .. .. ..$ headers:List of 6  
  .. .. .. ..$ content-disposition: chr "attachment; filename=\"groups-2016-0318-063749.csv\""  
  .. .. .. ..$ content-type       : chr "text/csv"  
  .. .. .. ..$ date               : chr "Fri, 18 Mar 2016 18:37:49 GMT"  
  .. .. .. ..$ server             : chr "Apache-Coyote/1.1"  
  .. .. .. ..$ transfer-encoding  : chr "chunked"  
  .. .. .. ..$ connection         : chr "Close"  
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"  
  ..$ cookies    :'data.frame': 6 obs. of  7 variables:  
  .. ..$ domain    : chr [1:6] "somewebsite.org" "#HttpOnly_.site.org" "signin.site.org" ".site.org" ...  
  .. ..$ flag      : logi [1:6] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE  
  .. ..$ path      : chr [1:6] "/" "/" "/" "/" ...  
  .. ..$ secure    : logi [1:6] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE  
  .. ..$ expiration: POSIXct[1:6], format: "2017-03-18 12:37:16" NA NA NA ...  
  .. ..$ name      : chr [1:6] "fs_experiments" "ObSSOCookie" "TS01289383" "TS01b89640" ...  
  .. ..$ value     : chr [1:6] "u%3D-anon-%2Ca%3Dshared-ui%2Cs%3Dac76fc702b255a493a5856b5432b92b4%2Cv%3D0100110011010000000111111111001110101101000000000001100"| __truncated__ "15yUK2dU%2B78GK7o587gtwh3i%2ByORXGD8ne5XJBiGkiHpDAJ3%2F7rQ4Gql6T5DqQIwCg%2FSwSioAMIzzaRxGEFKsCkc%2BGohi1fdWhbR0urah6%2BJikm9lA6"| __truncated__ "01999b7023d69473f53740d0f7f2969d9d79e1a18c7e259f6baf643ce642a330fc0a3604d7" "01999b7023960237ab42ec3f429e5a452fe3559d683a090b19a65cf66ce0c01bc21bdb29bf78f030d36d4eeff4dec21ff185c54b06" ...  
  ..$ content    : raw [1:45857717] 69 64 2c 6e ...  
  ..$ date       : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-03-18 18:37:49"  
  ..$ times      : Named num [1:6] 0 0 0.062 0.156 27.425 ...  
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...  
  ..$ request    :List of 7  
  .. ..$ method    : chr "GET"  
  .. ..$ url       : chr "https://somewebsite.org/report/groups"  
  .. ..$ headers   : Named chr "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*"  
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Accept"  
  .. ..$ fields    : NULL  
  .. ..$ options   :List of 4  
  .. .. ..$ useragent    : chr "libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/0.9.6 httr/1.0.0"  
  .. .. ..$ cainfo       : chr "C:/Users/Thisuser/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/httr/cacert.pem"  
  .. .. ..$ autoreferer  : int 1  
  .. .. ..$ customrequest: chr "GET"  
  .. ..$ auth_token: NULL  
  .. ..$ output    : list()  
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "write_memory" "write_function"  
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "request"  
  ..$ handle     :Class 'curl_handle' <externalptr>   
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "response"  
 $ html    :<environment: 0x000000001aad2f60>   
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "session"
```

Comment: Try `library(httr); library(readr); read_csv(mydata$content)` and see if that works.

Comment: Ananda, That worked wonderfully.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data are stored in the list item named "content". `read_csv` from the "readr" package should be able to read it directly.

Try the following:

```
library(httr)
library(readr)

read_csv(my.data$content)
```